# How to compress a series of PNG for loading?

Tags: javascript, canvas, png, gif

I have got a series of PNG for a game character, such as `stand.png, run1.png, run2.png`.

I would like to load them for drawing a series of action in javascript canvas. As the size of `.png`, I have to load almost 2 MB for one character if there are about 50 frames for one character.

So any idea about compressing these similar PNGs, by some methods like `diff` algorithms?

Comment: I would like to use GIF, but seems that I can not fetch or control a single frame of GIF in JavaScript.

Comment: If you’re looking for compression/small file sizes, GIF probably isn’t the way to go…

Comment: Have you tried running your PNGs through [Pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) and/or [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm)? I’ve found they often shave off some of the file size of PNGs, particularly when used in combination. (Sometimes PNGOUT will palettize the image but not otherwise compress very well; Pngcrush can then use PNGOUT’s palette and compress the bits better.)

Comment: Use sprites to reduce the overhead of having a lot of requests for individual images.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Image_Sprites

Comment: Actually what I like is to reduce the redundancy of these similar pictures. Because the frames for an action contains a large redundancy, there is only tiny difference between two frame.

Answer (score 3):

First remove all the blank space (Transparent) around the characters. This may result in images that are different sizes, you will have to store the offsets and sizes in a file. A simple JSON file to describe your character sprites will do the job.

Check for similarities between sprites. Run1.png and Run2.png may have the top half identical just offset, so trim it off and store that as one image and the two running legs images separate.

JPG images do not store transparent pixels but can be very compact. Consider storing the transparent pixels in a separate 8bit compressed png image or a custom binary format. 4 bits is good for most transparency requirements. Then you can store the colour info in jpgs saving you a lot of data.

Make sure you don't send sprites that are just mirrors or rotations of other sprite. Do the mirroring and rotations at the client.

If each sprite is small and you wish to use png format consider 8bit colour lookup format rather than 32 bit RGBA. If you have sprites that are the same but just the colours are different you can create a separate pallet for them rather than a separate image and on the client just replace the pixel colours with the new pallet.

If the character is carrying something, eg a gun, remove the gun and store it in a separate image. Add it back at load time or keep it separate and add it at render time.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw all your character states on one png, and load that png file (png sprite) to browser.For example you can do that on this site http://css.spritegen.com/. Then you can draw parts of png sprite in canvas.